# automation studio - daylight savings

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

I have automations scheduled in EST in automation studio. Emails cant send during these automations. Users were told not to send at 5am and 5pm EST. They reporting since daylight savings earlier this year they are hitting clashes at 4am and 4pm EST.

Support told us that the time zones would be respected but this doesn't seem to be the case. Does anyone know how to solve the issue?

Comment: I'd escalate the case until you get an answer.  If what they're telling you doesn't match the behavior in the platform, then press the issue.  Be prepared to slog it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received an answer about the timezone:

Automation time zone: runs in Central Time which does not change for daylight savings and always remains the same

Time zone selected when scheduling automation: converts the Automation time zone just for the UI. This does not ensure the automation will run consistently at the chosen time.

e.g.for EST time zone running every 4 hours

2 November 2019 - schedule is at 4, 8, 12 am/pm
3 November 2019 - schedule automatically changes to 3, 7, 11 am/pm

7 March 2020 - scheduled at 3, 7, 11 am/pm
8 March 2020 - schedule automatically changes to 4, 8, 12 am/pm